# Error when trying to insert data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony4

I am using the following method to add data to the database:

```
public function updatePayment($data) {
    $result = 0;
    $payment = new Payment();

    // Payment is 'before'
    if (isset($data['payday'])) {
        if ($data['payday'] == 'before') {
            $payment->setBefore(1);
            $payment->setAfter(0);
            $payment->setBeforeAfter(0);
            $result = 1;
        }
        elseif ($data['payday' == 'after']) {
            $payment->setBefore(0);
            $payment->setAfter(1);
            $payment->setBeforeAfter(0);
            $result = 1;
        }
        elseif ($data['payday'] == 'before_after') {
            $payment->setBefore(0);
            $payment->setAfter(0);
            $payment->setBeforeAfter(1);
            $result = 1;
        }
    }
    if ($result == 1) {
        $this->em->persist($payment);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO payment (work_id,
>   task_id, before, after, before_after, milestone, min, max,
>   hourly_rate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null,
>   null, 1, 0, 0, null, null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'before,
>   after, before_after, milestone, min, max, hourly_rate) VALUES (NULL,
>   NUL' at line 1

This is how my table looks like:

[image]

I only want to add values to the columns `before`, `after` and `before_after`. So I don't think that I have to insert values to other columns as well, since the default value should be `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately you have chosen column names (`before` and `after`) that are [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-B) that *must* be enclosed in backticks when used in a query.

Comment: Weird that a framework never adds backticks by default to column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before` and `after` are [reserved words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

You would need to use backticks to escape them in the query, like:

```
INSERT INTO payment 
    (work_id, task_id, `before`, `after`, before_after, milestone, min, max, hourly_rate) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

So in symfony, something like:

```
<?php
/** @Column(name="`before`", type="integer") */
private $before;
/** @Column(name="`after`", type="integer") */
private $after;
```

A better option would be to simply rename the colums to something else.

Comment: Good to know about that. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @RezaSaadati, glad that it helped!